# Mobaxterm stop macro while running

Tags: macros, mobaxterm

How to stop Mobaxterm macro script?
Is there a command to cancel/stop the macro while it is running for Mobaxterm?

Answer (score 0):

There is a button Stop on the top-right of the Mobaxterm Window in the Toolbar of the script while it is running.

You can press Ctrl+C `^C` to stop or exit a command in the shell.